# How do I call window.external.notify within a worker thread?

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, internet-explorer-10

I have an HTML5 app that runs in a Windows Phone 8 browser control and communicates to C# via window.external.notify.

The app is muli-threaded via web workers, but they are unable to communicate to C# because they do not have access to the the window object. Hence this error:

```
'window' is undefined
```

Does anyone have ideas on how to get around this limitation?

Comment: you postMessage to the window, and have window talk to c#.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in C# perhaps wrapping the call using:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    // Make call here
});
```